# Shift click to extend marked region

Tags: emacs, mouse, selection

Suppose I want to select some text (mark a region) using my mouse, but without dragging. What I normally do (in most apps but `emacs`) is:

1. click with the left button of my mouse (`down-mouse-1`);
2. release my mouse, in to leave the cursor where I want the selection to begin;
3. press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key;
4. and finally click (`down-mouse-1`) again in the place of the text where I want the selection to end.

However, I cannot do this with `emacs`, because in step 4 a context menu pops up (`Change default buffer face`), and my selection gets lost.

I've tried remapping `<S-down-mouse-1>` to several other commands, with no success.

**Does someone know how to accomplish this feat in `emacs`?**

(I'm using `emacs` 24.2 on `Xubuntu` 12.04 and also on `Mac Os X` 10.8 (Cocoa Emacs); I'm using `transient-mode` and `cua-mode`.)

---

Update:

I have just tried this code, as suggested [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode), but also with no success.

```
  ;; shift + click select region
  (define-key global-map (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'ignore) ; turn off font dialog
  (define-key global-map (kbd "<S-mouse-1>") 'mouse-set-point)
  (put 'mouse-set-point 'CUA 'move)
```

Comment: If you press `C-h c`, hold the shift key, and then click somewhere in the text, what do you get in the echo area?  My Emacs says `<S-mouse-1> (translated from <S-down-mouse-1> <S-mouse-1>) at that spot runs the command mouse-save-then-kill` and behaves the way you want yours to behave.  I'm also on 24.2 on OS X, using transient-mode but not cua-mode.

Comment: @legoscia I added this to my init file, as you suggested, and it worked!!! `(define-key global-map (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'mouse-save-then-kill)`. (Please add it as an answer and I will acknowledge it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you don't have this binding already, but this seems to have fixed your problem, as per your comment:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<S-down-mouse-1>") 'mouse-save-then-kill)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the floowing in **~/.emacs** worked for me (I had the same issue with context menu popping instead of a selected region):

(global-set-key (kbd "S-") #'mouse-set-mark)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Cocoa emacs](http://www.emacsformacosx.com/)? I'm fairly certain the behavior you want works out of the box.

Comment: Well, I'm using it right now with no sucess.

Comment: Just tried running emacs with `emacs -q`, to see if something in my init files was messing up with the mouse's behavior, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried it with no configuration? (i.e. temporarily rename your `.emacs` so it won't be found). Perhaps there's something in there causing the problem. I have the exact same emacs and OSX versions as you and it works without a `.emacs`.

Comment: wow, that's bizarre. I can think of no remaining difference between our setups.